# Need help organizing a 2d array into weeks and days with sum and averages

Tags: c#

This is the code I have so far.  I need help organizing it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab_A
{
class Activity2DArrayA
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // initialize 2-d array to store steps & dates 
        // this array contains 4 rows (weeks) 
        // each row contains 7 columns (days)
        int[,] steps = {
            { 4835, 24794, 13827, 10470, 10210, 10310, 14868 },
            { 11384, 16781, 8090, 8565, 10666, 15162, 13828 },
            { 14246, 8416, 19782, 20617, 7700, 21225, 34826 },
            { 22881, 17980, 26924, 18568, 19299, 22164, 21992 },
        };
        int sum = 0;

        // loop thru array using nested for loop 
        // the outer loop controls the rows 
        // the inner loop controls the columns 
        for (int row = 0; row < steps.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("   week  " + (row + 1) +" ");


            for (int col = 0; col < steps.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                sum += steps[row, col];


                double average = sum / 28;
                Console.WriteLine("average: {0}", average);
                Console.WriteLine("total: {0}", sum);
```

I can get week 1-4 to appear for the rows but I need help with adding days of the week to the column with the total and averages

Comment: Maybe `double average = sum / 28.0;`

Comment: *What* shall the totals and averages mean? Your code example is incomplete and it's absolutely unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: so write a line saying "monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday" or whaever you need.. display the relevant array value underneath...

Answer (score 0):

For daily average, you can do something like this:

```
//declare outside of loops
var dayStepAverages 
    = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, int>()
    {
        //this sort of initialization assumes you're using C# 6.0
        [DayOfWeek.Monday] = 0,
        [DayOfWeek.Tuesday] = 0,
        [DayOfWeek.Wednesday] = 0,
        [DayOfWeek.Thursday] = 0,
        [DayOfWeek.Friday] = 0,
        [DayOfWeek.Saturday] = 0,
        [DayOfWeek.Sunday] = 0
    };

//in inner loop
dayStepAverages[(DayOfWeek)col] += steps[row,col];
```

For weekly, do something like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < steps.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    //inside of first loop
    var weeklyTotal = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < steps.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        //inner loop
        weeklyTotal += steps[row, col];
    }
    var averageForWeek = weeklyTotal / 7;
    //store averageForWeek in a list or something.
}
```

Comment: thanks ill try that, and sorry if I wasn't clear about the organization, I need it to look like this

Comment: I'm trying to post a picture of what I talking about but its basically a table with week 1-4 on the left and the steps organized into days of the week at the top

Comment: Once you have the numbers, you can put them into any sort of UI/output you'd like, but that's a different question than summing the values.